# salvaging Binary code in SAS

Tags: sas

I am working with a large SAS database and it appears that a few of the columns were derived from binary sources and forced into a character format.  I believe this is the case because all sorts of crazy characters are appearing in the column: @@, ??, the "female" symbol to name a few.  Is there a way to salvage this data and convert in to a usable format, or do I need to correct the way the table is populated from the original data source.

Comment: I think you need to work upstream... Once the data is messed up like that, the best you can do is probably to just get rit of it. Can you provide more info on the data source(s) posing problems?

Comment: Could it be encoding issue rather then binary code? You will need to look where the data is coming from to understand what encoding is being used. In case of encoding, you might be able to reformat the data to make it meaningful.

Comment: What kind of data do you expect in these columns?  Text?  Numbers?  Is it possible they're stored in PIB (Packed Integer Binary) format, or something similar?